# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^{n}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

I don't know from which point I have to start finding this limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^{n}}dx$$

Comment: Do you have access to the dominated convergence theorem? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: Just for curiosity, the value of the integral for $n=1...10$ according to Mathematica:
$$
\left\{\frac{\pi}{e},\frac{\pi}{e},\frac{7\pi}{8e},\frac{37\pi}{48
e},\frac{133\pi}{192e},\frac{2431\pi}{3840e},\frac{27007\pi}{46080
e},\frac{176761\pi}{322560e},\frac{5329837\pi}{10321920e},\frac{12994393\pi
}{26542080e}\right\}
$$

Comment: For any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, the sequence should converge pointwise to something simple.

Comment: Rewrite $(1+x^2)^n$ as $e^{n \log{(1+x^2)}}$ and apply Laplace's method.  The result is $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Answer (score 5):

Letting $t=\sqrt nx$ gives
$$\sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^{n}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt n})}{(1+\frac{t^2}{n})^{n}}dt. $$
By using $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$ for $x>0$, one has
$$ \left|\frac{\cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt n})}{(1+\frac{t^2}{n})^{n}}\right|\le \frac{1}{1+t^2}. $$
Noting 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\pi<\infty, \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{t^2}{n})^{n}=e^{t^2},$$
by the DCT, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^{n}}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt n})}{(1+\frac{t^2}{n})^{n}}dt\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt n})}{(1+\frac{t^2}{n})^{n}}dt\\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt\\
&=&\sqrt{\pi}.
\end{eqnarray}